# Embedding citations using natbib and chicago or APSR

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm trying to embed citations using natbib and chicago style but I keep coming up short. The errors I get include: 'Cite should not be used with natbib. Use Sort instead; Latex Error: Somethings wrong perhaps a missing item. I'm using a [Wu thesis template](https://computing.artsci.wustl.edu/latex-style-files) that I've altered a bit, hence the name umslthesis.cls. Below is the CLS and the Tex file, along with the bib file. Thanks.

```
 \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{umslthesis}[2006/12/15 Wash U Math thesis class]
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\ifthen}[2]{\ifthenelse{#1}{#2}{}}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{wulongtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\makeatletter
\def\@@number{\string##}


\newcommand{\@@type}{thesis}
\newcommand{\set@@type}[1]{\renewcommand{\@@type}{#1}}
\DeclareOption{bypass}{\set@@type{bypass}}
\DeclareOption{prelim}{\set@@type{prelim}}
\DeclareOption{thesis}{\set@@type{thesis}}
\newboolean{@@uglyheadings}
\setboolean{@@uglyheadings}{false}
\DeclareOption{uglyheadings}{\setboolean{@@uglyheadings}{true}}
\newboolean{@@unset}
\newcommand{\@@optionbibstyle}{}
\newcommand{\set@@optionbibstyle}[1]{\renewcommand{\@@optionbibstyle}{#1}\addtocounter{@@tcount}{1}}
\DeclareOption{abbrvnat}{\set@@optionbibstyle{abbrvnat}}
\DeclareOption{agsm}{\set@@optionbibstyle{agsm}}
\DeclareOption{aip}{\set@@optionbibstyle{aip}}
\DeclareOption{alpha}{\set@@optionbibstyle{alpha}}
\DeclareOption{apalike}{\set@@optionbibstyle{apalike}}
\DeclareOption{astron}{\set@@optionbibstyle{astron}}
\DeclareOption{chicago}{\set@@optionbibstyle{chicago}{sort}}
\DeclareOption{ieee}{\set@@optionbibstyle{ieee}}
\DeclareOption{ieeetr}{\set@@optionbibstyle{ieeetr}}
\DeclareOption{kluwer}{\set@@optionbibstyle{kluwer}}
\DeclareOption{plain}{\set@@optionbibstyle{plain}}
\DeclareOption{plainnat}{\set@@optionbibstyle{plainnat}}
\DeclareOption{unsrt}{\set@@optionbibstyle{unsrt}}
\DeclareOption{unsrtnat}{\set@@optionbibstyle{unsrtnat}}
\DeclareOption{apsr}{\set@@optionbibstyle{apsr}}

\newif\if@openbib
\@openbibfalse
%


%\DeclareOptions*(\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
  % Used to count number of citation/bibliography styles used.

\ProcessOptions
\newcommand{\IW}[1]{\immediate\write16{#1}}
{
  \catcode`\+=13
  \def+{\space}
  \ifnum\value{@@tcount}>1
    \IW{}
    \IW{You may specify only one citation/bibliography style from the below list:}
    \IW{++++abbrvnat}
    \IW{++++agsm}
    \IW{++++aip}
    \IW{++++alpha}
    \IW{++++apalike}
    \IW{++++astron}
    \IW{++++chicago}
    \IW{++++ieee}
    \IW{++++ieeetr}
    \IW{++++kluwer}
    \IW{++++plain}
    \IW{++++plainnat}
    \IW{++++unsrt}
    \IW{++++unsrtnat}
    \IW{++++apsr}
    \IW{ABORTING...}
    \IW{}
    \stop
  \fi
}
\LoadClass[12pt,twoside]{report}[2001/04/21]


{\obeyspaces
  \gdef\@@Identification{{
    \IW{}
    \IW{+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+}
    \IW{|                                                                            |}
    \IW{|                         Thanks for using wuthesis.cls.                     |}
    \IW{|                                                                            |}
    \IW{+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+}
    \IW{}
}}
}

\def\AppendixFigure{\relax}
\def\AppendixTable{\relax}
\def\@@bibname{REFERENCES}
\def\@@deptbibstyle{chicago}
\def\@@coversheetspace{\vfill}
\def\@@evenfoot{}
\def\@@evenhead{\hfil\textrm{\thepage}}
\newboolean{@@figurecaptions}
  \setboolean{@@figurecaptions}{false}
\def\@@oddfoot{}
\def\@@oddhead{\hfil\textrm{\thepage}}
\def\@@sectionbaselinestretch{\relax}
\def\@@sectionseries{\bfseries}
\def\@@startthebibliography{\coversheet{\@@bibname}}
\def\@@startvita{\coversheet{\@@vitaname}}
\def\@@subsectionbaselinestretch{\relax}
\def\@@subsectionseries{\bfseries}
\def\@@subsubsectionbaselinestretch{\relax}
\def\@@subsubsectionseries{\bfseries}
\def\@@t{\relax}
\def\@@thebibliographyparsep{\relax}
\def\@@makechapterhead#1{\large\bf\thechapter. #1}
\def\@@makechapterheadspacea{\vspace*{0.5truein}}
\def\@@makechapterheadspaceb{\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}
\def\@@makeschapterheadspacea{\vspace*{0.5truein}}
\def\@@makeschapterheadspaceb{\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \usepackage{notoccite}
}
\AtEndDocument{
  \@@Identification
%%  \write\@auxout{\string\newcounter{\string\csname@@@appendix\endcsname}}
%%  \write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{\string\csname@@@appendix\endcsname}{\arabic{@@appendix}}}
}
\newenvironment{cland}
  {\begin{landscape}\hbox\bgroup\hss\vbox\bgroup}
  {\egroup\hss\egroup\end{landscape}}

\newenvironment{lquotation}
  {\begin{quotation}\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\reset@font}
  {\end{quotation}}

\newcommand{\coversheet}[1]{
  {
    \ifthen{\boolean{@@coversheets}}
      {
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@@chapterblankpages}}
          {\clearpage} %% ! {\cleardoublepage}
          {\clearpage}
        \pagestyle{empty}
        \mbox{}
        \@@coversheetspace
        \begin{center}
          #1
        \end{center}
        \vfill
        \newpage
        \addtocounter{page}{-1}
      }
    \@@NotTableOfContents
  }
}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11truein}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5truein}
\renewcommand*{\baselinestretch}{2}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5truein}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5truein}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.75truein}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6truein}
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newcommand{\@@NotTableOfContents}{%
  \renewcommand*{\@evenhead}{\@@evenhead}
  \renewcommand*{\@oddhead}{\@@oddhead}
  \renewcommand*{\@evenfoot}{\@@evenfoot}
  \renewcommand*{\@oddfoot}{\@@oddfoot}
}


\newcommand*{\@@MajorProf}{\relax}
\newcommand*{\majorprof}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@@MajorProf}{Professor #1, Chairperson}}
\newcommand*{\majorprofs}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@@MajorProf}{Major Professors: #1}}
\newcommand*{\@@Title}{\relax}
\renewcommand*{\title}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@@Title}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@@Committee}{\relax}
\newcommand*{\committee}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@@Committee}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}
  {
    {
      \renewcommand*{\baselinestretch}{2} \reset@font
      \setcounter{save@@page}{\value{page}}
      \begin{titlepage}
        \mbox{}
        \vfil
        \vfil
        \begin{center}
        {\Large\bf University of Missouri-St. Louis\\}
        {\large Political Science }
        \vskip 0.4truein
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\reset@font
        { Dissertation Examination Committee:\\
         \@@Committee
        }
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}\reset@font
        \vskip 0.5truein
        \uppercase\expandafter{\@@Title}
        \end{center}
        \ifthen{\(\boolean{number@@all@@volumes} \and \value{last@@volume}>1\) \or \value{@@volume}>1}
          {
            \begin{center}
              VOLUME \the@@volume
            \end{center}
          }
        \vfil
        \begin{center}
          by\\
          \@@TitleAuthor
        \end{center}
        \vfil
        \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\reset@font
        \begin{center}
          A dissertation presented to the \\ Graduate School of Arts and Sciences\\ of the University of Missouri-St. Louis in\\ partial fulfillment of the\\
          requirements for the degree\\
          of
          \@@TitleDegree
        \end{center}
          {}
          {\vfil}
        \begin{center}
          \@@DegreeMonth\ \@@DegreeYear\\
          St. Louis, Missouri 
        \end{center}
      \end{titlepage}
      \setcounter{page}{\value{save@@page}}
      \ifthen{\value{@@volume}=0 \or \value{@@volume}=1}
        {\setcounter{page}{2}}
    }
  }
\newenvironment{dedication}%
  {%
    \newpage
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \mbox{}
    \vfil
    \begin{center}%
  }%
  {%
    \end{center}%
    \vfil
    \eject
    \@@NotTableOfContents
  }
\newboolean{@@inother}
\setboolean{@@inother}{false}
  % #1 "next" or "odd": start on next or next odd page?
  % #2 what to print at top of page
  % #3 "y" or "n": put in table of contents?
  % #4 amount of extra space to put after heading at top of page
\newcommand{\@@nonchapter}[4]{{%
  \@@NotTableOfContents
  \bgroup
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \setboolean{@@inother}{true}
    \renewcommand{\large}{}%
    \renewcommand{\bf}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{ce}{\@@dept}}
      {\chapter*{\uppercase{#2}}}
      {\chapter*{#2}}
    \ifthen{\equal{y}{#3}}
      {
        \ifthenelse{\equal{ce}{\@@dept}}
          {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{#2}}}
          {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}}
      }
  \egroup
  \vspace{#4}
}}
\newenvironment{acknowledgments}%
  {\@@nonchapter{next}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}{y}{0pt}}%
  {}
\newenvironment{preface}%
  {\@@nonchapter{next}{PREFACE}{y}{0pt}}%
  {}
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{
  \@@nonchapter{odd}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}{n}{0pt}
  {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{\hfil Page}\par}
  {%
    \output={
      \let \par \@@par
      \ifnum \outputpenalty<-\@M
        \@specialoutput
      \else
        \@makecol
        \@opcol
        \@startcolumn
        \@whilesw \if@fcolmade \fi
          {%
           \@opcol\@startcolumn}%
      \fi
      \ifnum \outputpenalty>-\@Miv
        \ifdim \@colroom<1.5\baselineskip
          \ifdim \@colroom<\textheight
            \@latex@warning@no@line{Text page \thepage\space
              contains only floats}%
            \@emptycol
          \else
            \global \vsize \@colroom
          \fi
        \else
          \global \vsize \@colroom
        \fi
      \else
        \global \vsize \maxdimen
      \fi
      {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{\hfil Page}\par}
    }
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}\reset@font
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \@starttoc{toc}
  }
}
\def\bigtocskip{0.5\baselineskip plus.2\p@}
\def\smalltocskip{0pt}
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth
  \else
    \vskip #2
    {%
      \leftskip #3
      \rightskip \@tocrmarg
      \parfillskip -\rightskip
      \parindent #3
      \@afterindenttrue
      \interlinepenalty\@M
      \leavevmode
      \@tempdima #4
      \advance\@tempdima \@@padding
      \advance\leftskip \@tempdima
      \hbox{}\hskip -\leftskip
      #5\nobreak
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu.\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill
      \nobreak
      \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hfil\reset@font\rm #6}\par
    }%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand*{\listoftables}{
  \@@nonchapter{next}{LIST OF TABLES}{y}{0pt}
  {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{Table\hfil Page}\par}
  {%
    \output={
      \let \par \@@par
      \ifnum \outputpenalty<-\@M
        \@specialoutput
      \else
        \@makecol
        \@opcol
        \@startcolumn
        \@whilesw \if@fcolmade \fi
          {%
           \@opcol\@startcolumn}%
      \fi
      \ifnum \outputpenalty>-\@Miv
        \ifdim \@colroom<1.5\baselineskip
          \ifdim \@colroom<\textheight
            \@latex@warning@no@line{Text page \thepage\space
              contains only floats}%
            \@emptycol
          \else
            \global \vsize \@colroom
          \fi
        \else
          \global \vsize \@colroom
        \fi
      \else
        \global \vsize \maxdimen
      \fi
      {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{Table\hfil Page}\par}
    }
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\reset@font
    \@starttoc{lot}
  }
}
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{
  \@@nonchapter{next}{LIST OF FIGURES}{y}{0pt}
  {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{Figure\hfil Page}\par}
  {%
    \output={
      \let \par \@@par
      \ifnum \outputpenalty<-\@M
        \@specialoutput
      \else
        \@makecol
        \@opcol
        \@startcolumn
        \@whilesw \if@fcolmade \fi
          {%
           \@opcol\@startcolumn}%
      \fi
      \ifnum \outputpenalty>-\@Miv
        \ifdim \@colroom<1.5\baselineskip
          \ifdim \@colroom<\textheight
            \@latex@warning@no@line{Text page \thepage\space
              contains only floats}%
            \@emptycol
          \else
            \global \vsize \@colroom
          \fi
        \else
          \global \vsize \@colroom
        \fi
      \else
        \global \vsize \maxdimen
      \fi
      {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{Figure\hfil Page}\par}
    }
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\reset@font
    \@starttoc{lof}
  }
}
\newcommand{\@@startlist}[1]{
  \@@nonchapter{odd}{#1}{y}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\LTleft}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\LTright}{0truein}%
  \setlength{\@@tlength}{\textwidth}
  \addtolength{\@@tlength}{-\LTleft}
  \addtolength{\@@tlength}{-\LTright}
  \addtolength{\@@tlength}{-\tabcolsep}
  \addtolength{\@@tlength}{-\tabcolsep}
  \addtolength{\@@tlength}{-1truein}
}
\newenvironment{symbols}%
  {%
    \@@startlist{SYMBOLS}
    \begin{longtable}{lp{\@@tlength}}%
  }
  {\end{longtable}}
\newenvironment{abbreviations}
  {
    \@@startlist{ABBREVIATIONS}
    \begin{longtable}{lp{\@@tlength}}%
  }
  {\end{longtable}}
\newenvironment{nomenclature}
  {
    \@@startlist{NOMENCLATURE}
    \begin{longtable}{lp{\@@tlength}}%
  }
  {\end{longtable}}
\renewenvironment{glossary}
  {
    \@@startlist{GLOSSARY}
    \begin{longtable}{lp{\@@tlength}}%
  }
  {\end{longtable}}
\renewenvironment{abstract}%
  {%
    \@@nonchapter{next}{ABSTRACT}{y}{0pt}
    {%
      \renewcommand*{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\reset@font
      \vspace*{\baselineskip}
      \vbox{
        \begin{center}
        \noindent
        {\bf \@@Title}\\
         by\\
        \@@AbstractAuthor~\\ \@@AbstractDegree \ in Political Science,\\
       University of Missouri-St. Louis,
        \@@DegreeMonth,
        \@@DegreeYear.\\
        {%
          \renewcommand*{\\}{}%
        }
        \@@MajorProf
       \end{center}
      }

      \vspace*{\baselineskip}
      \par
    }
  }%
  {\par}
  \pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \ifthenelse{
        \(      \boolean{@@inother} \and \boolean{@@nonchapterblankpages} \)
    \or \( \not \boolean{@@inother} \and \boolean{@@chapterblankpages}    \)
  }
    {\cleardoublepage}
    {\clearpage}
  \@@NotTableOfContents
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef \@chapter \@schapter
}
\newboolean{@@inchapters}
\setboolean{@@inchapters}{false}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
    \setboolean{@@unset}{true}
  \fi
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{ce}{\@@dept}}
    {\@makechapterhead{\uppercase{#2}}}
    {\@makechapterhead{#2}}
  \@afterheading
  \ifthen{\not \boolean{@@inchapters}}
    {
      \pagenumbering{arabic}%
      \@@inchapterstrue
    }
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\protect\numberline{\csname thechapter\endcsname}{\bf #1}}}
}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \@@makechapterheadspacea
  {\centering
    \@@makechapterhead{#1}
    \endgraf
  }
  \@@makechapterheadspaceb
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \@@makeschapterheadspacea
  {\centering
    \ifthenelse{\equal{ce}{\@@dept}}
      {\large\bf\uppercase{#1}}
      {\large\bf #1}
    \endgraf
  }
  \@@makeschapterheadspaceb
}
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec
    \leavevmode
  \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty{\@secpenalty}%
    \addvspace{\@tempskipa}%
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}%
}
\newenvironment{cabstract}{\begin{quote}\textbf{Abstract}\quad}{\end{quote}}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}[section]
\newsavebox{\proofbox}
\sbox{\proofbox}{\rule{7pt}{7pt}}
\newtheorem{Proof}{Proof}
\renewcommand{\theProof}{}
\newenvironment{proof}{\begin{Proof}\rm}{\hfill \usebox{\proofbox} \end{Proof}}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection
    {section}%
    {1}%
    {\z@}%
    {24pt}%
    {12pt}%
    {\@@sectionbaselinestretch\reset@font\@@sectionseries}%
}
\ifthen{\boolean{@@uglyheadings}}
  {
    \def\undertext#1{$\underline{\smash{\hbox{#1}}}$}
    \def\section{
      \vspace{36truept}
      \secdef{\@@section}{\@@ssection}
    }
    \def\@@section[#1]#2{
      \refstepcounter{section}
      \sectionmark{#1}
      \hbox to \textwidth{\hss\undertext{\thesection\ #2}\hss}\nopagebreak
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\csname thesection\endcsname}#1}
      \nopagebreak
    }
    \def\@@ssection#1{
      \sectionmark{#1}
      \hbox to \textwidth{\hss\undertext{#1}\hss}\nopagebreak
      \nopagebreak
    }
  }
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \@startsection
    {subsection}%
    {2}%
    {\z@}%
    {24pt}% \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {12pt}% 1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\@@subsectionbaselinestretch\reset@font\@@subsectionseries}%
}
\ifthen{\boolean{@@uglyheadings}}
  {
    \renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
      \refstepcounter{subsection}
      \vspace{36truept}
      \subsectionmark{#1}
      \hbox to \textwidth{\hss\thesubsection\ #1\hss}\nopagebreak
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\csname thesubsection\endcsname}#1}
      \nopagebreak
    }
  }
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{
  \@startsection
    {subsubsection}%
    {3}%
    {\z@}%
    {24pt}% \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {12pt}% 1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\@@subsubsectionbaselinestretch\reset@font\@@subsubsectionseries}%
}
\ifthen{\equal{mse}{\@@dept}}
  {
    \def\undertext#1{$\underline{\hbox{#1}}$}
    \newbox{\@@Strut}
    \renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{
      \refstepcounter{subsubsection}
      \vspace{6truept}
      \subsubsectionmark{#1}
      \noindent \undertext{\vphantom{gjpqy}\thesubsubsection. #1}\newline\nopagebreak
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect\numberline{\csname thesubsubsection\endcsname}#1}%
      \nopagebreak\indent
    }
  }
\ifthen{\boolean{@@uglyheadings}}
  {
    \renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{
      \refstepcounter{subsubsection}
      \vspace{36truept}
      \subsubsectionmark{#1}
      \noindent \undertext{\thesubsubsection. #1}\newline\nopagebreak
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect\numberline{\csname thesubsubsection\endcsname}#1}
      \nopagebreak
    }
  }
\ifthen{\boolean{@@uglyheadings}}
  {
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
    \newcommand*{\l@subsubsubsection}{\@dottedtocline{4}{\smalltocskip}{11.2em}{5.0em}}
    \def\subsubsubsectionmark#1{}
    \newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
    \renewcommand{\thesubsubsubsection}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
    \newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{
      \refstepcounter{subsubsubsection}
      \vspace{36truept}
      \subsubsubsectionmark{#1}
      \noindent \thesubsubsubsection. #1\newline\nopagebreak
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsubsection}{\protect\numberline{\csname thesubsubsubsection\endcsname}#1}
      \nopagebreak
    }
  }
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef\@svsec{\csname the#1\endcsname\hskip 1em}%
  \fi
  \ifthen{\equal{che}{\@@dept}}
    {%
      \ifnum #2=3
        \refstepcounter{#1}%
        \edef\@svsec{\csname the#1\endcsname\hskip 1em}%
      \fi
    }%
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6\relax
      \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
      {\interlinepenalty \@M #8\par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
      \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7%
    }%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6%
      \hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8\csname #1mark\endcsname
      {#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
        \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}
        \fi
        #7%
      }%
    }%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}%
}
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}{\@dottedtocline{0}{\bigtocskip}{0em}{1.4em}}
\ifthen{\equal{ece}{\@@dept}\or \equal{hsci}{\@@dept}}
  {\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\figurename~\thefigure.}
\renewcommand{\fnum@table}{\tablename~\thetable}
\newboolean{@@centercaption}
\renewcommand{\caption}{%
  \setboolean{@@centercaption}{true}
  \refstepcounter\@captype \@dblarg{\@caption\@captype}%
}
\newcommand\bcaption{%
  \setboolean{@@centercaption}{true}
  \refstepcounter\@captype \@dblarg{\@caption\@captype}%
}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vspace*{\abovecaptionskip}
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{@@centercaption}}  % center caption
    {
      \setlength{\@@captionwidth}{\textwidth}
      \addtolength{\@@captionwidth}{-4\@@parindent}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{figure}{\@captype} \or \boolean{@@figurecaptions}}
        {
          \sbox\@tempboxa{#1 #2}%
          \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\reset@font
          \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
            \centerline{\parbox[t]{\@@captionwidth}{#1 #2}}
          \else
            \centerline{#1 #2}%
          \fi
        }
        {
          \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\reset@font
          \centerline{#1}
          \sbox\@tempboxa{#2}%
          \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
            \centerline{\parbox[t]{\@@captionwidth}{#2}}
          \else
            \centerline{#2}%
          \fi
        }
      \vspace*{\belowcaptionskip}
    }
    {
      \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
      \begin{quote}
        \renewcommand{\\}{}
        \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\reset@font
        \ifthenelse{\equal{aae}{\@@dept}}
          {#1. #2\par}
          {
            \ifthenelse{\equal{table}{\@captype}}
              {\hfil\strut #1\hfil\break #2\par}
              {#1 #2\par}
          }
      \end{quote}
    }
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip
}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{5\p@}
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \baselineskip=12pt
  \noindent
  \@makefnmark #1%
}
\ifthenelse{\equal{}{\@@optionbibstyle}}
  {\newcommand{\@@bibstyle}{\@@deptbibstyle}}
  {\newcommand{\@@bibstyle}{\@@optionbibstyle}}
\ifthen{\equal{abbrvnat}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{{\normalsize\rm REFERENCES}}
    \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
  }
\ifthen{\equal{agsm}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {
    \usepackage{harvard}
    \bibliographystyle{agsm}
  }
\ifthen{\equal{aip}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {
    \usepackage{revtex}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{{\normalsize\rm REFERENCES}}
    \bibliographystyle{aip}
  }
\ifthen{\equal{alpha}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {\bibliographystyle{alpha}}
\ifthen{\equal{apalike}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {\bibliographystyle{apalike}}
\ifthen{\equal{astron}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {\bibliographystyle{astron}}
\ifthen{\equal{chicago}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{chicago}
    \bibliography{transfer}
  }
\ifthen{\equal{ieee}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {\bibliographystyle{ieee}}
\ifthen{\equal{ieeetr}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}}
\ifthen{\equal{kluwer}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {
    \usepackage{harvard}
    \bibliographystyle{kluwer}
  }
\ifthen{\equal{pumeunsrt}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {\bibliographystyle{pumeunsrt}}
\ifthen{\equal{plain}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {\bibliographystyle{plain}}
\ifthen{\equal{plainnat}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{{\normalsize\rm REFERENCES}}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  }
\ifthen{\equal{unsrt}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {\bibliographystyle{unsrt}}
\ifthen{\equal{unsrtnat}{\@@bibstyle}}
  {
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{{\normalsize\rm REFERENCES}}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
  }

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
  {
```

TEX FILE

```
\documentclass{umslthesis}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
% set the correct origin
\setlength{\pdfvorigin}{0pt}
% Put your thesis title below.
%
\title{A Nation Divided: Assessing the Regional Effects of Institutional Capacity, Social Capital, and Civic Culture on Tax Morale in Italy}

% Put your name here.
% First one is the name you want to put on the cover.
% Second is the one you want to use in abstract.
\author{John D'Attoma}{D'Attoma, John}

% Put your Degree here.
% First is long title of degree (used on cover).
% Second is abbreviation for degree (used in abstract).
% Third is the month the degree was (will be) awarded (used on cover
% and abstract).
% Last is the year the degree was (wlll be) awarded (used on cover
% and abstract).
% The degree title for all doctoral candidates is ``Doctor of Philosophy.''
\wudegree{Doctor of Philosophy}{Ph.D.}{December}{2015}

% Put your advisor's name here.
\majorprof{Dr. Joyce Mushaben}

% List the names of the members of the committee here.
\committee{Dr. Joyce Mushaben, Chair\\Dr. Kenneth Thomas, Co-chair\\Dr. David Kimball\\Dr. Fred Cocozzelli}

% You may put your own abbreviation here.
\input{mydefs}

\begin{document}

\volume

\include{front}
\include{ch01}
\include{ch02}
\include{ch03}
\include{ch04}
\include{bib}

\end{document}

@book{Putnam:2001wa,
Author = {Putnam, Robert D},
Date-Added = {2014-06-07T03:24:23GMT},
Date-Modified = {2014-06-07T03:24:24GMT},
Isbn = {0743219031},
Language = {English},
Month = aug,
Publisher = {Simon and Schuster},
Rating = {0},
Read = {Yes},
Title = {{Bowling Alone}},
Year = {2001}}
```

Comment: The class file you've posted appears to have gotten truncated and is thus, I'm afraid, currently not usable for meaningful testing. If I compile your code using the regular wuthesis document class file, I experience no problems.

Comment: I had to truncate it for it to fit. I'm using basically the same wuthesis.cls. Can you explain to me how you were able to get the citation to work and where you inserted the \usepackage{natbib}, \bibliographystyle{...}, \bibliography{...}? Thanks.

Comment: The `\usepackage{natbib}` statement (like all `\usepackage` statements) belongs in the preamble. The `\bibliographystyle` directive can occur either in the preamble or somewhere in the body of the text. The `\bibliography` statement should occur where you want the bibliography to show up -- usually toward the end of the document.

Comment: Should this be in the preamble of the Cls or the tex file? Thanks.

Comment: I think I've figured out that you're supposed to specify the bibliography style as one of the document class options. If you do specify `chicago` as this option, the `natbib` package will be loaded automatically and the instruction `\bibliographystyle{chicago}` will be executed as well. See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `wuthesis` document class wants you to specify the bibliography style as an option to the `\documentclass` command. If, say, `chicago` is specified, the `natbib` package will be loaded automatically; no need for you to repeat this process. You also needn't specify the bibliography style separately if it's been set as a document class option.

If I specify "chicago" as the document class, the following MWE compiles fine (remember to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes). In particular, the bibliography page looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[chicago]{wuthesis}

\title{A Nation Divided: Assessing the Regional Effects of Institutional Capacity, Social Capital, and Civic Culture on Tax Morale in Italy}
\wudegree{Doctor of Philosophy}{Ph.D.}{December}{2015}
\majorprof{Dr.\ Joyce Mushaben}
\committee{Dr.\ Joyce Mushaben, Chair\\
           Dr.\ Kenneth Thomas, Co-chair\\
           Dr.\ David Kimball\\
           Dr.\ Fred Cocozzelli}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Putnam:2001wa,
  Author = {Putnam, Robert D},
  Date-Added = {2014-06-07T03:24:23GMT},
  Date-Modified = {2014-06-07T03:24:24GMT},
  Isbn = {0743219031},
  Language = {English},
  Month = aug,
  Publisher = {Simon and Schuster},
  Rating = {0},
  Read = {Yes},
  Title = {Bowling Alone},
  Year = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\cite{Putnam:2001wa}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You've been very helpful. I have one last question and my document should be all set for my dissertation. Is there a way to put a hanging indent in my bibliography page?

Comment: Glad this has been helpful. Regarding getting hanging indentation of the bib entries: It looks to me like the document class has seriously doctored the `thebibliography` environment and, in the process, obliterated the normal hooks for setting up hanging indentation. In short, I can't provide an easy solution.